# Не могу вывести сообщение об ошибке при пустом поле email

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring-mvc, freemarker

пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при вводе пользователем пустого email выводилось сообщение об ошибке, однако как не бьюсь - не выходит(с другими полями получилось)

Вот контроллер:

> @Controller @RequestMapping("/user") public class UserController {
>       @Autowired
>       private UserService userService;
>
> ```
> @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
> @GetMapping
> public String userList(Model model) {
>     model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
>     return "userList";
> }
>
> @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
> @GetMapping("{user}")
> public String userEditForm(@PathVariable User user, Model model) {
>     model.addAttribute("user", user);
>     model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
>     return "userEdit";
> }
>
> @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
> @PostMapping
> public String userSave(
>         @RequestParam String username,
>         @RequestParam Map<String, String> form,
>         @RequestParam("userId") User user) {
>
>     userService.saveUser(user, username, form);
>
>     return "redirect:/user";
> }
>
> @GetMapping("profile")
> public String getProfile(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
>     model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
>     model.addAttribute("password", user.getPassword());
>
>     return "profile";
> }
>
> @PostMapping("profile")
> public String updateProfile(
>         @Valid User user,
>         BindingResult bindingResult,
>         Model model,
>         @RequestParam String password,
>         @RequestParam String email) {
>
>     if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
>         System.out.println(model.containsAttribute("emailProfileError"));
>         Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);
>         model.addAttribute("emailProfileError", "The email field cannot be empty");
>         model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);
>         System.out.println(model.containsAttribute("emailProfileError"));
>     }
>     else {
>         userService.updateProfile(user, password, email);
>     }
>     System.out.println(model.containsAttribute("emailProfileError"));
>     return "redirect:/user/profile";
> } }
> ```

Тут все ок, выводит как положено false-true-true, т.е. сообщение об ошибке в model кладется

Вот фронт:

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>

<@c.page>
    <h5>${username}</h5>
    ${message?ifExists}
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" name="email"
                       class="form-control ${(emailProfileError??)?string('is-invalid', '')}"
                       placeholder="some@some.com"
                       value="${email!''}" />
                <#if emailProfileError??>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        ${emailProfileError}
                    </div>
                </#if>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form> </@c.page>
```

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: Читайте про валидаторы в Spring. Оно как раз про валидацию данных от клиента на сервере. Если кратко, то в контроллер даже не будет передаваться управление, если данные от пользователя не валидны. Читать про аннотацию `@Validated` и интерфейс `Validator`

Comment: @zolt Если честно, пока не понял в чем проблема. Ясно, что фронт не видит атрибуты из Model. Однако, в абсолютно аналогичных ситуациях(подобным образом у меня идет проверка пустых полей при логине, например, или при отправке сообщения) все в порядке. Если вы мне укажете чего конкретно не хватает - будет очень круто.
Возможно, туплю, глаз уже замылился.